# View inside cell have the same width in all devices but cell has different

Tags: ios, swift

I am using table view and given constraints (top,letf,right,bottom) and its printing width same in all devices but cell width is different in all devices.
But the problem is i have taken view inside cell and given constraint again same (top ,left right,bottom) , and width of view when printed is same in all devices. How it can be possible ? My cell width is different and its content view has same width in all devices? 
What am missing while constraints please explain this to me ?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: yes it is marked in storyboard

Comment: I have to give width to view programmatically equal to the by default content view of cell ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the image bellow.
Maybe you are not using Auto Resize Contraints for the view you have taken inside the cell.

[image]

Comment: Please look at above images , cell is adjusted by its own in all devices.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The view with red background is given constraint and autoresize subview is marked on storyboard .

and its showing like this still[image]

override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

```
    //Corner Radius to cell contnt view
    view_ContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    view_ContentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    view_ContentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    view_ContentView.clipsToBounds = true
    view_SubServices.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
   self.CreateDynamicLabelOnView(px: 2.0, view: view_SubServices, array: ["Hair Trimming" ,"Hair Color","Dry Cleaning","Boutique","Washing"],textColor:UIColor.white,backgroundColor: Common.k_Purple)

}
```

func CreateDynamicLabelOnView(px:CGFloat,view:UIView,array:NSMutableArray,textColor:UIColor,backgroundColor:UIColor){

```
    var px:CGFloat = 2.0
    var tx:CGFloat?


    array.enumerateObjects({ (obj, idx, stop) in

        var width =  (obj as! String).widthOfString(usingFont: UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 13.0)!)

        if width < 30.0{
            width = 45.0
        }

         print(width)
         print(px)
         print(view.frame.size.width)
            tx = px  + width
         print(tx!)
        //            if width < view.frame.size.width && tx! < view.frame.size.width {
        if tx! < view.frame.size.width {

            let label = UILabel(frame:CGRect(x: px, y: 2.0, width: width , height: 25.0))
            label.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
            label.textColor = textColor
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 12.0)
            label.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0
            label.text = array[idx] as? String
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            label.clipsToBounds = true
            view.addSubview(label)

            px = px  + label.frame.size.width + 5
        }
        else{
            stop.pointee = true
        }


    })

}
```